# Excluding data using NOT IN in the join using DB2, SQL PL

Tags: join, db2, inner-join

I need assistance in formulating the correct approach to a query.

I have staff members that I need to give work to.  If they're not available on a date, they're excluded from the group of staff members that can get work.  I think it's clear what I'm trying to do, but it's incorrect syntax:

```
INNER JOIN mySchema."STAFF" S
ON RS.STAFF_ID = S.STAFF_ID
AND RS.STAFF_ID NOT IN (SELECT SU.STAFF_ID 
FROM mySchema."STAFF_UNAVAIL" SU
WHERE SU.UNAVAIL_DT = OUTSTANDING_DATE)
```

Any ideas on how one could achieve a NOT IN in a join without actually doing it in the join?

Comment: providing the complete query and the exact error you are getting would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

put it in a `where` clause after the joins

```
INNER JOIN mySchema."STAFF" S
ON RS.STAFF_ID = S.STAFF_ID
...any other joins...
WHERE RS.STAFF_ID NOT IN (SELECT SU.STAFF_ID 
FROM mySchema."STAFF_UNAVAIL" SU
WHERE SU.UNAVAIL_DT = OUTSTANDING_DATE)
```